# How to run command on remote machines via jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want Jenkins to run a command on a remote machine in my desired location.

For Ex-

- There is a openStack machine (say m1) [ 10.X.X.X ]
- Jenkins command should navigate to  ‘/my/desired/location/’ on machine ‘m1’ and trigger ‘ls’ command

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called Publish Over SSH [Link](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) that allows you to connect and execute your desired commands on a remote machine. You only have to ensure your Jenkins has visibility to the remote machine and you are good to go.